# Sending a IplImage through a socket with JavaCV

Tags: sockets, opencv, iplimage

I'd like to send IplImages acquired with JavaCV and a webcam through a socket, but, since they are not serializable, i'm quite lost. Any idea on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your image to temporary file and transfer that file through your socket.

If you don't want to create temporary files, you can get `ByteBuffer` with pixel data from `IplImage.getByteBuffer()` and write your own `writeObject` & `readObject` methods.

Comment: Thank you. I got the Bytebuffer for the image, converted it to a byte array and sent it over the socket. It seems it's working. How can i convert the array back to IplImage?

Comment: @Spaffo: Create new `IplImage` with the same format. Get it's `ByteBuffer` and put received data into it.